# Filtrar y sumar campos de una base de datos en el cliente o en el servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una base de datos que contiene una tabla que a su vez contiene un campo de tipo de dato entero. El objetivo es filtrar esos enteros y sumar el resultado. Puedo hacer esa operación tanto en el cliente como en el servidor, pero debo elegir uno de los dos. Quisiera saber dónde es mejor hacer una operación de este tipo, por motivos de seguridad y rendimiento.

El contexto es web, y uso mysql y php en el servidor.

Comment: ¿Qué crees que sea más seguro entre un cliente y un servidor? ¿Qué equipo tiene mejor desempeño: el de tus clientes o el de tu servidor? Es un desperdicio que viajen por la red datos que no se utilizan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para este ejemplo debes tener en cuenta algunos aspectos.

1. Quien va filtar? un sistema o un usuario?
2. Si va filtrar un sistema solo es necesario hacer el query respectivo desde dicho backend a la base de datos.
3. Si va filtrar un usuario (desde el front) necesitas crear una petición http desde el cliente y crear un endpoint en el backend.